# Minimum current draw of AC to DC converter at no load

Tags: current, ac, dc, converter, conversion

I wanted to know if there is a minimum current draw on the AC to DC converters from the AC source when it is connected to an input voltage of 120V (60Hz), when no load is connected at the output of the converter ? Is this current draw constant ?

For example, if we consider this converter from progressive dynamics,
http://www.progressivedyn.com/power_converters_9100.html

If we consider the PD 9180, would there be any current draw from the AC source for this converter ?

Answer (score 1):

From the 'Inteli-Power Specifications Table' on the link you gave, I see that the no-load voltage is given to be nearly 13.6V, and guaranteed to be over 12.6V under full load. Clearly current will not be constant if you are changing the load; voltage on the other hand will be compensated for under a wide range of current draws. The unit will surely draw power even under no-load. It appears that there is no minimum current draw. I have heard, however, when going the opposite way (DC/AC converter) that some inverters will shut off under no load condition. Having no access to a schematic or the code running this thing, I can't say for certain, but it looks like it will work just fine under no-load conditions.